# How to specify which csv file using multiple get_cell

Tags: php, csv

I have a page with multiple `get_cell` functions within it that all successfully return a single cell value from a CSV file.

However, the first CSV file specified in the first instance is the one the rest pull information from. I have at least two different CSV files I need to reference on the same page.

How do I specify the CSV file, as well as the specific cell?

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('get_cell')) {
    function get_cell($cell, $row)
    {
        $file = 'CSV/filename.csv';

        $row = $row - 1;
        // Reset the $row if it's negative.
        if ($row < 0) {
            $row = 0;
        }
        $handle  = fopen($file, "r");
        $counter = 0;
        while (($csvline = fgetcsv($handle, 450, ",")) != false) {
            if ($counter == $row) {
                $new_array = array();
                $begin     = 'a';
                foreach ($csvline as $cellnr) {
                    $new_array[$begin] = $cellnr;
                    $begin++;
                }
                echo $new_array[strtolower($cell)];
            }
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}
get_cell('A', 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass in the file name as one of the arguments, with `CSV/filename.csv` as a default if you'd like:

```
function get_cell($cell, $row, $file="CSV/filename.csv")
{
    ...
}
get_cell('A', 1, "CSV/filename2.csv");
```

Comment: and remove the $file = 'CSV/filename.csv'; ? 

I'm struggling to get it to work, it still uses the first instance throughout?

Comment: @user2653322 - You have to also modify the function call to include the name. I've updated the answer to show an example.